# Who can identify this microphone?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, recording

Does anybody know what microphone (brand + model) the singer in this video is using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The video seems to be uploaded, distributed and recorded by https://www.undayrecords.be.

There is also a [link](https://www.facebook.com/taminoamir/) to the artist.

You could try to contact either the record label, or the artist for information on the recording equipment used.

I would start with the artist, as the video seems to be produced in what looks like a private bedroom.

Caveat: the microphone in the video is not necessarily the one which actually recorded the audio track. This may have been done in an actual studio and edited to the video at later stage.

Answer (score 1):

Looks somewhat like a Neumann M49 ([image](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bc/4c/b9/bc4cb9353b2cb2afff50c6da69395b68.jpg)), but its hard to see the details properly. The connector looks like it might be the same, but as the other answer says the only way to know for sure is to contact the artist or management.